# Cypress: Access the td next to a known one within a table

Tags: cypress

Can anybody help?

I need to write a cypress locator with a table name and the real name, but click on the checkbox in a td next to the real name label.
so far I have:

```
cy.contains('[tabletitle]', 'XYZ').should('be.lengthOf', 1)
      .closest('table')
      .contains('td', 'REALNAME').should('be.lengthOf', 1)
      .parentsUntil('tr[name='tr-xyz']')
      .get('input[type="checkbox"]').check();
```

I tried **closest** instead of **parentsUntil**, but it always jumps above the table name and then ergo click on all the input checkboxes of all the tables on the page. I want it to stay within a **tr** and just clicks on the checkbox in the above **td** (within the table).
Here is a scetch of the page:

```
<table name='xyz'><div tabletitle>XYZ</div>
  <tr name='tr-efg'>
    <td><div><div name='td-xyz'><input type="checkbox"></div></div></td>
    <td><div someOtherDiffsandTD></div>
    <td><div name='realName1'>REALNAME</div></td>
    <td ...etc
  <tr name='tr-efg'>
    ...same as first line with different realname
  <tr name='tr-efg'>
    ... etc ...
</table>
<table name='abc'>
  <tr name='tr-efg'>
  ...same as first table with first td containing a checkbox and second td a cell with the realname...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To navigate to the table element after selecting the tile, just use `.parent()` - assuming the table is the direct parent of the title element.

```js
cy.contains('div[tabletitle]', 'XYZ')  // tabletitle div with "XYZ"
  .parent()                            // table
  .should('be.lengthOf', 1)
  .within(() => {            // limit to this table

    cy.contains('tr', 'REALNAME')   // row with "REALNAME" in one of the columns
      .should('be.lengthOf', 1)
      .find('input[type="checkbox"]')  // find, not get 
                                       // otherwise all inputs on page are returned
      .check()                         // ✅ 
  })
```

I suspect the HTML you show isn't the full picture, there should be a `<tbody>` around the `<tr>` and the title is oddly placed, I would expect it to precede the `<table>`.

Comment: This "within" is indeed the solution. But you need a closest before the find otherwise it's stuck: .closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]')

Comment: For some reason since the text `XYZ` is wrapped in a div within the table, it can't be picked up with `.contains('table', 'XYZ')`.  if you the `name` attribute and `REALNAME` are unique among the tables, then you can sub that in for the first contains. 

`cy.contains('[name=xyz]', 'REALNAME')`

Comment: Yes, you're right. Table selectors behave differently to most other elements, best revert to getting the title div then traversing with parent.

Comment: Also `.parents('table')` should work but doesn't.